# htaccess Redirect to Sub Directories

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, apache2

So I Do have different folders in the var/www/html for different projects
I wanted to redirect **www.testing.com** to  **var/www/html/test**, so I added a **.htaccess** file and added the following in the file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} testing\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1 [L]
```

And it worked fine, now Im redirected to **/test** index file when I go to **www.testing.com** except that the assets in the website are not being retrieved. 

 
 
For example an image with **www.testing.com/images/k.png** url returns **404**. 
I dont want to change the urls of the images or any of the content, I need to redirect them to **/test** using **htaccess** configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you write  `^/$` in line 3 and it says than all of your urls end with `/` but `www.testing.com/images/k.png` is not end with `/` so you can change it to `^/(.*)$` it say that you can have somethings after `/` finally your code changed to :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} testing\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1 [L]
```

Comment: it gives me an internal server error 500. From apache logs it displays `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: by adding a line can correct it in your server, i edit my post, this new condition exclude urls that have test at the start